# What is the alternative function in HarmonyOS for onDraw in Android OS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am implementing a custom component in HarmonyOS using Java SDK. In Android to draw a custom view, we override the [onDraw](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing#overrideondraw) method from the View class.

In HarmonyOS the Component class doesn’t have the onDraw method. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, `onDraw()` is not available in [Component](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/component-0000001054678683) class. But, we have another way to achieve the same functionality. You can `implements` [Component.DrawTask](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/component_drawtask-0000001054678675) in your custom component to implement the same functionality. You would need to call addDrawTask in the constructor to add a drawing task.

So, your Custom component code will look like this -

```
import ohos.agp.components.AttrSet;
import ohos.agp.components.Component;
import ohos.agp.render.Canvas;
import ohos.app.Context;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

public class CustomComponent extends Component implements Component.DrawTask {
    
    public CustomComponent(Context context, @Nullable AttrSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        addDrawTask(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Component component, Canvas canvas) {
        //Do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onDraw` method by implementing the `Component.DrawTask` interface. First you need to call `addDrawTask` in the constructor to add a drawing task. The sample code is as follows:

```
public class MyComponent extends Component implements Component.DrawTask {

    public MyComponent(Context context) {
        super(context);
        addDrawTask(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Component component, Canvas canvas) {
      // draw
    }
}
```